# changing icon's color in a listview

Tags: flutter

i am trying to change the color of icon in  my listview but not able to. also, im trying to round an icon in a circle but also cannot do.

below is my code that i have so far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class CardviewListItem {
  //final FlatButton icon;
  final Icon icon;
  final String title;
  final String amount;

  const CardviewListItem({
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.amount,
  });
}
```

```
import 'package:finsec/model/cardview_list_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/utils/strings.dart';

const summaryListItems = <CardviewListItem>[
  CardviewListItem(
      title: 'Total Income',
      amount:'4434.65',
      icon:
      Icon(
        icon: Icons.widgets,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),

  ),

];
```

the above code is not working.  i get error message in android studio before running the code.  error: 1 required argument expected but 0 found.

currently the icon im using from material icon is

[image]

i want to turn the icon into this:

[image]

is there a way to change the color of icon and add rounded circle around the icon using code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to stack a circle container and the icon. Try a function a like this and modify the content to see if this works. The Container uses `BoxDecoration` to create the green circle. Then the `Stack` places the green circle below the icon.

Let me know if you need additional help.

```
  makeIconWithCircle() {
    final circle =  Container(
      height: 25.0,
      width: 25.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        shape: BoxShape.circle
      ),
    );
    final icon = Icon(
      Icons.attach_money,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 18,
    );

    final iconWithCircle = Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        circle,
        icon
      ],
    );

    return iconWithCircle;
  }
```

To make this work with your code, I think you can do something like this. Without your entire file, I cannot confidently say this will work with a copy and paste. You may need to adjust some stuff as needed.

```
@immutable
class CardviewListItem {
  //final FlatButton icon;
  final Widget icon; // this is a widget. Not an icon.
  final String title;
  final String amount;

  const CardviewListItem({
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.amount,
  });
}


class SomeOtherClass {
final summaryListItems = <CardviewListItem>[
  CardviewListItem(
      title: 'Total Income',
      amount:'4434.65',
      icon: makeIconWithCircle(Icons.attach_money) // call function to create an icon with a circle in the background.
  ),
];


  static Widget makeIconWithCircle(IconData iconData) { // function takes in the icon you want to create with a green background
    final circle =  Container(
      height: 25.0,
      width: 25.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        shape: BoxShape.circle
      ),
    );
    final icon = Icon(
      iconData, // iconData paramater is used here
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 18,
    );

    final iconWithCircle = Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        circle,
        icon
      ],
    );

    return iconWithCircle;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your help.  how can i use this function my code? should i call it in CardviewListItem   as  icon: makeIconWithCircle()

Comment: @yoohoo I've updated my code example to show how it could be used. I updated the function so that it takes in an `iconData` argument when called. 

I call the function in `SomeOtherClass`.

Comment: Thank you Alex, it is looking good. one more question.  how can access the variable summaryListItems  in class SomeOtherClass from another class that is stateless?  before i was able to call the variable as   cardView(listItems: summaryListItems)    CardView been a separate file which define a stateless widget.  now that you wrap summaryListItems  in a class, how can i access this variable from CardView stateless class?  my apologies but i am a newbie in flutter

Comment: I think you should ask a new question with the code where you are experiencing this problem. I can answer it, however, it is outside the scope of this question. Once you create a new question, send me a link and I'll see how I can help.

If I answered this question correctly, could you mark it as correct?